# Update tycho pom & manifest via Maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, tycho

I have integrated a tycho java project and generated a pom manually for this. This pom is used by a parent pom to build my maven projects. I'm searching for a way to define the version of this sub project and changing the manifest in one step. I tried the tycho-version-plugin but this plugin will update the pom when the manifest is changed (correct me if I'm wrong). Has anybody ever encountered this problem and has a solution? Any hint could help.

Comment: Which one of the [tycho-versions-plugin goals](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/plugin-info.html) did you use? There are two of them...

Comment: I only know the manifest-driven goal "tycho-versions:update-pom" which would update my pom if the project would be manifest-driven.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418013

Comment: [Your edit is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) because it completely changes the scope of the question. Open a new question instead.

Comment: No bounty can be given right now. Question was edited and was classified as outdated. I will ask again with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The [`update-pom` goal](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/update-pom-mojo.html) of the Tycho versions plug-in in fact only adapts the POM version so that they match the manifest version. This is for example useful for projects that use the Eclipse API tooling which suggests to update manifest versions, but doesn't know about the POM version. So in case of such an update, `update-pom` could be used to mirror the changes to the POM versions.

For your use case however, you want the use the [`set-version` goal](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/set-version-mojo.html), which updates both manifest and POM versions at once.

Comment: While it may seem obvious now that the `set-version` goal shall be used, this wasn't the case when this question was originally asked: Until April 2014, the goal didn't have any [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/plugin-info.html). This question was one of the reason why I added the documentation. (Disclaimers: I'm a committer on the Tycho project but I did not author the tycho-versions-plugin.)